# How to insert yyyy-yyyy date format in MySQL database via VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i can only insert date format like this `yyyy` in my database with a datatype of `YEAR(4)` from VB.NET with this code:

`SQL = "INSERT INTO tblyear(year) VALUES(NOW())"`

i'm planning to insert `this year - next year`, its like what you call `School Year`.

Comment: why don't you use 2 columns?

Comment: IF this is to do with schools why not store the DATE the school year starts and the DATE the school year ends?

Comment: what do you mean by store? have it input by textbox? because my instructor recommends me not to input a school year but have it automatically inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Daniel, you should probably just store the current year and have the display code format things the way you want. But if you need to do it this works:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO tblyear(year) VALUES (CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',(YEAR(NOW()) + 1)))"
```

Comment: but is has error `Data truncated for column 'year' at row 1` ?